# A gravity question

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

Does gravity have a unit like length is metres?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of text here, hopefully it's not too much and makes at least a little sense. $\ddot\smile$

There are several units for gravity, depending on how you model gravity and what you're looking to calculate. Energy, in Joules ($J$); or spacetime distortion, but I don't know the units, both measure the "absolute" amount of gravity near a point, and are useful for calculating how much energy you need to get away from a massive object.

Force per mass, in Newtons per kilogram ($N\over kg$); or acceleration, in either gees ($g$) or meters per second squared ($m\over s^2$), are both useful for measuring the deflection of a small object as it passes through a massive object's gravity field.

TL;DR explanations are bolded, near the middle for the edited answer, and near the bottom for the original answer.

***Answer for updated question "does gravity have a unit":***

One model of gravity, as mentioned below, is basically an energy field surrounding every object in the universe. In this case, you could ostensibly measure the total strength of the field in one location to get the amount of gravity there.

Another model of gravity is that gravity literally distorts space (and time) near any object with mass. In this case, you'd measure the amount of distortion at any given point. This is related to [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) and [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations).

Either way, you're effectively measuring the strength of the gravity. However, the strength of the gravity isn't particularly relevant in these models. What *is* relevant is how the strength changes with distance. Objects will always go from areas of low gravity towards areas of high gravity, and the larger the difference per meter, the faster the objects will accelerate. In this way, you can model gravity like a hill, with high gravity being the bottom of the hill, and low gravity being the top of the hill -- if you're near the top of the hill and don't do anything, you'll tend to roll towards the bottom of the hill, and the slope of the hill tells you how fast you accelerate.

The slope of the hill is a vector calculus problem, but here's the gist of it if you're not familiar with calculus.

In gradeschool, you learned that the slope of a line is its vertical change divided by its horizontal change (rise over run):

[image: Linear graph with delta x and delta y marked. Slope equals delta y over delta x.]

With curvy lines, it's a little harder. In [calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus) you learn(ed) that we can compute the slope at a point by getting the slope of a line near the point, then taking the [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) as we make the horizontal change arbitrarily close to zero (this is called the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)):

[image: Curvy graph with various x and y points marked. Slope equals the limit as delta x goes to zero of delta y over delta x.]
[image: Same curvy graph with three tangent lines added, each getting successively closer to the limit.]

We can do the same thing in two or three dimensions, but it's more complicated. This is the subject of [multivariable calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus). Basically, we take different slices to get the slope in different directions (these are called [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative), with one partial derivative per dimension). Using some more calculus, we can find the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of the function, which basically tells us the slope in the most "uphill" direction, and which direction that is.

[image: Curvy, two-dimensional surface with tangent plane and gradient vector shown pointing up and down the steepest direction of the hill.]
<sub><sup>Taken from a [mathematica.se](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69816/visualizing-the-gradient-vector) post.</sup></sub>

So we draw a big graph of space, where most of space is flat, with about zero gravity. Then really massive objects create a lot of gravity near them. On a normal graph, we would represent "high" gravity as a taller hill, but for our analogy it makes more sense to have high gravity look like a hole, or valley. Then we can think of things rolling down the hill into the hole.

[image: Fairly flat, two-dimensional surface, with several "massive" objects sitting on it. Each object creates indents in the surface that are analogous to gravity wells.]
<sub><sup>Taken from a [random blog post](http://blog.edecker.net/2015/08/gravity-wells/) by Decker Labs.</sup></sub>

That image is a 2D analogy rendered in 3D. For our 3D universe, you could do the same thing, but it would need to be rendered in 4D, which is a little tricky.

Anyways, using these models, gravity would be measured two ways. At its core, it would be measured either as "gravitational energy at a point", or as "spacetime deformation at a point" (depending on what model you're using). These *are* useful directly, because they tell us how much energy we need to get out of the "gravity well" and back to normal space. **This energy is measured in Joules ($J$).**

But the real units of gravity would be the derivatives -- "rate of change of gravitational energy near a point" or "rate of change of spacetime deformation near a point". **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field) says the former is measured in units of Newtons per kilogram ($N\over kg$), but I'm not sure about the latter.**

Fortunately, you don't really need to come up with units for gravitational energy or spacetime deformation, although it's already been done. It turns out that we can express the gravitational energy by measuring the acceleration of an arbitrarily small object at that point. Here, "arbitrarily small" means something small enough it doesn't significantly affect the gravity in the area, such as an apple near a planet.

**And those are the same units I listed below: gees ($g$), or meters per second squared ($m\over s^2$).**

***Old answer to "what's the gravity of the Earth", which is still fairly applicable:***

"Gravity" comes from Latin or French or something and means "weight". But weight isn't actually an intrinsic, constant property of an object. What is constant is "mass" (which is a little weird in origin, but basically means "a bunch of stuff gathered in one place"). Mass basically means "how hard is it to push this object away from me?" and is directly related to inertia. Mass is also directly related to gravity.

There are different theories or models about the nature of gravity, but its effect is well-understood: more massive objects produce proportionally more gravity. So if one object is 100 times as massive as another, the first produces 100 times more gravity.

But gravity also depends on distance. Particularly, it's inversely proportional to the square of distance. $G\propto {1\over D^2}$. So if you're twice as far away, there's one quarter of the gravity. Of note, distance is measured from the center of the objects, not the surface.

You can think of gravity as a series of energy waves that are constantly emitted from an object. The energy in that wave is spread throughout a spherical shell that expands away from the object over time. The surface area of a sphere is two-dimensional, so it's proportional to the square of radius: $A=4\pi R^2$. The energy in a shell is constant, but the area of the shell is expanding. So the energy per square meter is decreasing. This isn't the prevailing model of gravity, but it's useful to visualize the exponential decrease in gravitational strength over distance.

Now, the amount of that energy that hits another object is proportional to the other object's mass. So a massive object absorbs a lot of energy, while a light object only absorbs a little energy. I don't know of a geometrical way to visualize this, but it's linear. If an object is twice as massive, it absorbs twice as much gravity, and is therefore tugged on twice as hard. The amount of "tugging" is the "weight" of an object. So the weight of an object depends on the mass of planet pulling it, how far the planet is, and how massive the object itself is -- not very useful at all in astronomical terms as a base measurement (though it sees a lot of use as part of a larger calculation).

Now, this brings up an interesting point. A 100 kg person gets tugged on twice as hard as a 50 kg person, so their legs need to be stronger to support their weight. But 100 kg is harder to move than 50 kg, exactly twice as hard, in fact. So if both people jump out of an airplane, they'll fall just as fast, at least for several seconds before air resistance starts playing a huge role in the physics. If they jumped out over the moon, where there's no air, they'd fall the same rate for as long as they fell (but they'd need something besides a parachute to land safely!).

As N.S. John points out in a comment, this means most everyday objects fall towards the ground at the same rate. And because gravity is a function of distance, and the planet is almost spherical, it's almost the same rate anywhere on the planet, for any object. For Earth, the rate is about 9.8 meters per second, per second. This means an object accelerates from 0 to 9.8 $m\over s$ over the first second, then from 9.8 to 19.6 $m\over s$ over the next second, etc.

For other planets, the number is different. On the Moon, it's about 1.6 $m\over s^2$. On Mars it's about 3.8 $m\over s^2$. Note however, that the acceleration isn't directly linked to the mass. The Moon's mass is about 1.2% of Earth's mass, but its gravity is 16% as strong. That's because the moon is also a lot smaller, so you're closer to the center of gravity if you're standing on the moon. The moon is about 25% of the Earth's radius, or $1\over 4$. Since gravity is *inversely* proportional to distance, being closer means the gravity is stronger. So the relative acceleration is $A\propto 1.2\%(mass)\cdot {1\over ({1\over 4})^2(radius)}$ $=0.012\cdot 4^2$ $=0.012\cdot 16$ $\approx 16\%$.

This relative acceleration is also proportional to the relative weight of an object. So a 100 kgf person (as measured on Earth) weighs only 16 kgf on the Moon. (Note, "kg" is a measure of mass, while "kgf" is a measure of force. 1 kgf is the weight of a 1 kg object as measured on Earth. Most scales just call them both kg, but for physics you'll want to differentiate. In this case, the person has 100 kg mass whether he's on the Earth or the Moon, but his weight changes from 100 kgf to 16 kgf.)

Of course, that only applies to spherical objects when you're near the surface. A potato-shaped asteroid, for example, wouldn't have constant acceleration everywhere.

Note that gravity works both ways. Every single object, even the monitor you're reading this on, creates gravity. There's just so little mass in your monitor you don't notice that it's tugging on you. Similarly, a hammer technically falls a little faster than a feather (even with no air) because it's pulling up on the planet harder than the feather, but the planet moves only the tiniest amount, so the difference is insignificant. However, when talking about two planets or stars tugging on each other, the difference is more significant. In fact, we've discovered some planets in other star systems because we can see the star wobbling a bit from the planet's tugging.

**So when we talk about the "gravity" of the Earth in astronomical terms (where planets, stars, and moons are very far apart), the best way to describe it intrinsically is to talk about its mass, which is about $6\cdot 10^{24}$ kg. A human is around $6\cdot 10^1$ kg, so the Earth is as massive as $10^{23}$, or a hundred billion trillion, humans.**

**When we talk about the "gravity" of the Earth in terms of people walking around on the surface, the best way to describe it intrinsically is to use its surface acceleration, or 9.8 $m\over s^2$.**

When we talk about other planets, it can be useful to describe them relative to the Earth. For example, Jupiter is about 317 Earth masses (written as $317 M\oplus$), and Io has about 18% Earth gravity (written as 0.18g). When talking about stars, we use Solar masses (written as $M\odot$), although we rarely talk about their surface gravity (stars don't really have a "surface", and you couldn't survive walking there anyways).

Comment: Great answer but i changed the question a little, can you update your information?

Answer (score -1):

Gravity (g), is the acceleration that the Earth imparts to objects on or near its surface. It is measured in metres per second squared (m/s2). The gravitational force on Earth is different from that of other planets as the force is determined by the size of the planet, thus why when astronauts walked on the moon they were almost floating. Gravity also determines how much something will weigh on Earth, due to the calculation of mass x gravity.

Comment: This answer is a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you mean something like that gravity is just measured in m/s2?

Comment: Yes, gravity is measured in metres per second squared (m/s2). But as MichaelS says below, the calculation varies depending on the distance, mass etc.

Comment: I don't like this answer because gravity is much more general than just how much something weighs on Earth.

Answer (score -1):

using G ,u can find magnitude of acceleration of any Celestial body.Earth has different radii of curvature at poles and equators. so magnitude of gravity is different at different earth positions